# eclipse e4 (Juno) : Not able to hide view Part minimize/maximize buttons

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, eclipse-juno, e4

within part stack, i have part views. , and each view has minimize/maximize buttons,

Is there is any way i can hide minimize/maximize buttons for some particular view part ?

Answer (score 5):

This is a bug in e4:
https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=394231

There are two different ways to work around this:

1. Remove this dependency org.eclipse.e4.ui.workbench.addons.swt
2. Use this CSS-snippet:

   .MPartStack {
       swt-maximize-visible: false;
       swt-minimize-visible: false;
   }

Comment: i am using CSS.. it is working fine...                                                                                              


 MPartStack { 
              swt-maximize-visible: false;
              swt-minimize-visible: false;
            } 
                                                                                             MPartStack { swt-maximize-visible: false; swt-minimize-visible: false; }

Answer (score 1):

But there is another bug if you apply rule as below:

```
.MPartStack { 
    swt-maximize-visible: true; 
    swt-minimize-visible: false; 
}
```

- Initially "Minimize" button is hidden.
- If you maximize a part stack, now "Minimize" button is visible and you can really minimize the part stack.

`MinMaxAddon#setCTFButtons(..)` does not respect what css rule said, which always reveal the "Minimize" button for maximized part stack.